# Pop up flowing out of a video container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have simple HTML 5 video player, I have a function which opens a pop up when the current time is 0:07s, unfortunately, the pop on a small device flow out of a div.

Problem in graphic:

[image]

I want the popup to be centered in inside a video player in all devices like this.
[image: Pop up inside a video player]

Here is Plunker of what I am trying to do: [HTML 5 Video Player](https://plnkr.co/edit/F67QubFfAs3t5HkwBUhS)

Here is HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
        <video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay="true">
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.

        </video>
        <div class="lightbox popUpQuestion1">
            <div class="row row-no-padding">
                <div class="product-left-col">
                    <div class="product-main-pic">
                        <div id="imgContent">
                            <!-- Sinon si pas de coloris et pas de default Sku
                                        -> Affiche le premier SKU. -->
                            <img id="popinMainPic" src="http://www.sephora.pl/media/catalog_ProductCatalog/m11470681_P2264_princ_medium.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-right-col">
                    <div class="prodcut-title">
                        <H1>Rose Deep Hydration Moisturizer</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description-text">
                        An ultra-hydrating gel cream powered
                        by hyaluronic acid and time-release
                        technology for petal-soft skin.
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <span>299,00 zł</span>
                    </div>
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.sephora.pl/Makijaz/Oczy/Kredki-do-oczu-i-khol/Mini-kredka-do-powiek/P2255003?skuId=315720">
                        <div class="buy-button animates-in show">KUP TERAZ </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of Container -->
```

Here is css I have so far

```
body{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0em 0em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p{
    margin: 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

video{
    width: 1266px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.descArea{
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #c8c8c8;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* .videoArea{
    position: relative;
} */
.video-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.box1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(40, 169, 220, 0);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 630px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(207, 50, 53, 0);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.lightbox{
    display: none;
}

.longBtns{
    display: block;
}
.buy-button {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 182px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    /* right: 10px; */
    /* bottom: 41px; */
}
.product-modal{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 65em;
    height: 46.3em;
}
.row-no-padding{
    display: flex;
}

.sku-label-brand{
    font-family: georgia;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
}
.description-text {
    margin-top: 1%;
    line-height: 1.4;
    /* font-size: 1.7em; */
    /* width: 50%; */
    font-size: 24.444px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.product-right-col{
    width: 60%;
}
.product-left-col{
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 45px;
}
#popinMainPic{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sku-link{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.product-price{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
}
.prodcut-title > h1{
    font-size: 30.556px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 14px
}

.vjs-marker{
    width: 6px !important;
    border-radius: 30%;
    background-color: white !important;
    margin-left: -3.5px;
    left: 29.2002%;
    height: 6px !important;
    border-radius: 100px !important;
    bottom: 11px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 100px !important;
    -o-border-radius: 100px !important;
}

.video-js .vjs-big-play-button {
    display: none !important;
}
.vjs-has-started .vjs-control-bar {

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.69) 99%,rgba(0,0,0,.7) 100%);
}

.video-js{
    width: 100% !important;
}

.video1-dimensions {
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
}

.featherlight .featherlight-content{
    transform: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    -o-transform: scale(0.7);
}
```

I have tried to add `overflow:hidden` to parent div still the same.

What is wrong with my code? any idea or help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`featherlight` basically provides you a window sized popup that has `position: fixed` and is set to be placed at center horizontally and vertically. If you look at the CSS of featherlight, then you'll see it has `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;`. This is the intended behaviour of this plugin.

Moreover, the way this plugin works is by cloning your modal content to its own div and then displaying it. Hence giving you little less control over its positioning.

To override this behaviour, you need to manually calculate top, left and height of the video and then apply this to `.featherlight` by javascript. This would force the featherlight modal to be displayed over the video only irrespective of the the device width/height.

Hope this helps.